Civil Asset Forfeiture in dispute with large American company - Justification, Protection, and Spouse's Assets
I recently read about a case where the government seized assets from a former employee of a large corporation (Amazon) based on allegations of "honest services fraud" stemming from a contractual dispute. It looks more like a business dispute than a serious criminal case.
This specific case is detailed in this Twitter thread: https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1822318185556648348.html
You can google about "Amy Nelson's husband vs Amazon" for more information.
In the referenced case, the wife's assets were also seized, even though she was not a party to the civil dispute. Her husband was. I assume she was holding a joint account with her husband.
Here are my questions:

Is civil asset forfeiture legally justified in a business dispute regarding a contract?
What proactive steps can individuals take to mitigate the risk of civil asset forfeiture, particularly in the context of business disputes? Are there strategies for protecting assets from seizure?


FYI. This question is riddled with false assumptions and misunderstandings. No time to answer at length now. Civil forfeiture is not unconstitutional and has been held not to violate constitutional rights by the courts. Criminal charges generally aren't filed in connection with civil forfeiture. And honest services fraud is not just a contractual or business dispute, it is a criminal offense. This question is also probably over broad and needs more focus.

The twitter thread very specifically describes criminal charges. Here's one news report on this case, and another.

Question edited after reading comments above

If you're spending more time talking about the law and less time talking about the facts, you've probably written a low-quality question.

And just to follow up on @ohwilleke's comment, it's true that courts have found that "civil forfeiture is not unconstitutional," but that's a bit like saying that "gun restrictions are not unconstitutional." Both types of laws are the subject of well-coordinated and well-funded challenges in the courts, and the courts are very frequently finding that the laws we have in place are, in fact, unconstitutional. In other words, civil forfeiture isn't unconstitutional, but many (most?) civil forfeiture laws are.

@bdb484 I agree that there are well-coordinated challenges to the practice. I would disagree that it has been or is likely to be very successful in the courts (particularly with a very conservative SCOTUS), although legislative reforms have fared better.

@bdb484, I'll bear that in mind next time I asks a question.

This is (was) a case of criminality - it is not a contract dispute
The husband was charged with a crime. The assets were legally seized.
